# Switch for and foreach

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach, switching

I need to change my for loop to foreach loop in this method, how can i do that? ( Can add full class, if necessary)

```
public String decode(String input) {
    String[] letters = input.split(" ");
    StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i=0; i<letters.length; i++)
        ret.append(decodeMap.get(letters[i]));
    return ret.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should specify which language you are using. I'm assuming java. Use `for(datatype var : collection)`.
Here is what it would look like

```
public String decode(String input) {
    String[] letters = input.split(" ");
    StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();
    for(String s : letters){
                ret.append(decodeMap.get(s));
    }
    return ret.toString();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To avoid unnecessary creation of `StringBuilder` I would suggest something like that (assuming you are using Java 8+):

```java
    public String decode(String input) {
        String[] letters = input.split(" ");
        return Arrays.stream(letters)
                     .map(decodeMap::get)
                     .collect(Collectors.joining());
    }
```

Comment: "I would suggest..." Why? Also, `.map(decodeMap::get)`

Comment: That doesn't answer the question about for loop

Comment: Also, what makes you think your approach is better or faster? Streams API is not always faster than a traditional foreach loop.

Comment: This is why it is written as suggestion - to give the idea how to improve the code. Also now it includes explanation why: to avoid unnecessary creation of StringBuilder.

Comment: Well, the creation of the StringBuilder is not unnecessary, it's faster than normal string concatenation. Using less variables is not always an improvement.

Comment: Additional variables (and creation of objects) usually means the code looks more complex, you have to consider object that are not immutable etc. And if you would check `Collectors.joining` it also uses `StringBuilder` internally. And additional benefit of not solving the problem of joining the strings by yourself - any improvements in SDK will improve your code.